# Unable to add a <select> tag with a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

My goal is to add elements to an HTML form dynamically.
For this purpose, I have tried the following implementation methods:

- `appendChild( )` method available in Javascript
- `append( )` method available in jQuery

When I try to add basic HTML tags, they get added to the form successfully.

However, when the tag also has a class associated with it, the tag does not get rendered at all.

To be specific, I am trying to dynamically add [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) tags to a form, when a link is clicked. Adding `<select class="selectpicker"></select>` does not render a select tag.

Code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14901/)

Note: jsFiddle does render the < select > tag, but it is still not as expected. Any way, it does not get rendered on my local machine.

I have just started learning HTML and Javascript, so please give me some hints, if not direct answers, if I have made some mistakes.

Comment: Can you modify the fiddle to show your expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, on your demo page, you forgot to include bootstrap-select js and css files.

In your demo, you are not calling:

```
 $('select').selectpicker();
```

which is required to apply all styles to `select` tag.

After that, you have to call it in function callback, when the select tag is created dynamically.

Here is an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14905/

Comment: That works, thanks!
I want to learn a few things from your answer:

What is the utility of such a function: 
```
$(function() {
      $('select').selectpicker();
  });
```
What do you mean by "function callback" ?

Comment: The function callback will be executed, when specific event is fired. 

the: `$(function() { .. };` is jQuery callback which will be fired, when the jQuery is "ready" for use.

This code:
`$('select').selectpicker();`

is required by the bootstrap-select plugin: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/


In this example:
1. we waited until jquery is loaded and is ready for use.
2. we called the specific method on `select` tag to apply all styles.
3. after we created the select tag dynamically, we called that method once again.

Answer (score 0):

i have just converted your html code, put it into a string variable and it seems to work just fine, it behaves the same as your template
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/burim/DTcHh/14904/)

```
<script>

  var strVar="";
strVar += "Select: <select class='selectpicker'  name='selected_views'>";
strVar += "            <option value=\"X\">X<\/option>";
strVar += "            <option value=\"Y\">Y<\/option>";
strVar += "            <option value=\"Z\">Z<\/option>";
strVar += "  <\/select>";
strVar += "  <a href=\"#\" id=\"link1\" onclick=\"add_selectfield()\">Select<\/a>";

function add_selectfield() {
    $("#ff").append(strVar);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you should consider to remove directive 'multiple' from your append string?